# MySQL query to Mongo php

Tags: mongodb

I have mysql query like this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(id_station IN(1,2,3) AND datee >= "2017-08-01" AND datee <= "2017-08-02"), amount, 0) AS amount1,
SUM(IF(id_station IN(1,2,3) AND datee >= "2017-08-03" AND datee <= "2017-08-05"), amount, 0) AS amount2,
FROM report_cash
WHERE id_station IN(1,2,3) AND datee >= "2017-08-01" AND datee <= "2017-08-05"
GROUP BY id_station
```

How to convert to Mongodb? I tried with 2 $match in one query but no luck. This query used to compare total amount of 2 date ranges.

My mongo structure:

```
{"_id" : "59871e65fffe165420e0b324"
"receiptid" : "4BA/ZFY7AQ4HvfjUMTRTLg=="
"area_type" : 1
"report_type" : 3
"id_station" : 2317
"date" : "2017-08-05 00:00:00.000"
"time" : "1501979220"
"amount" : 10113958
"item" : 32
},
{"_id" : "59871e65fffe165420e0b324"
"receiptid" : "4BA/ZFY7AQ4HvfjUMTRTLg=="
"area_type" : 1
"report_type" : 3
"id_station" : 2317
"date" : "2017-08-05 00:00:00.000"
"time" : "1501979320"
"amount" : 4000000
"item" : 12
}
```

Here is the query:

```
$store = array(2441,2443);
$cursor = $collection->aggregate([
    ['$project'=> ['amount_current' => '$amountclient'] ],
    ['$match' => [ 'id_station' => ['$in' => $store ],
                    'date' => ['$gte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-03")*1000), '$lte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-05")*1000)]  
                 ] 
    ],            
    ['$match' => [ 'id_station' => ['$in' => $store ],
                    'date' => ['$gte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-01")*1000), '$lte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-02")*1000)]  
                 ] 
    ],
    ['$project'=> ['amount_prev' => '$amountclient'] ]
]);
```

Comment: Depends entirely on how you actually set up your data in MongoDB. Also usually requires that you "should" have realized that using a completely different database engine really required you to "re-design" rather than simply import every single table "as is" and then expect things to work in the same way. Show your data. Explain why you actually need to query this way, because there is probably a better data design for MongoDB. But please don't try to use StackOverflow as a "convert my code for me" service. Show some effort and you will get some help.

Comment: could you please see my addition? I really stuck on it

Comment: So `IF` in MySQL is a logical condition. If you actually looked at the [list of aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) then you "should" actually be able to see something that does something similar. As a "hint" we usually refer to the `if..then..else` sequence as a "ternary" condition.